# ggplot that looks like main effects plot in R, but is not

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to produce a chart that looks like a main effects plot, but does not come from a live analysis, just the output itself. Here is my data:

```
> gains.df
  var   level1   level2      gain
A  x1 12.44224 16.15509 -3.712853
B  x2 16.24322 12.35410  3.889120
C  x3 16.54085 12.05647  4.484381
D  x4 16.00008 12.59725  3.402832
E  x5 15.62463 12.97269  2.651939
```

The chart I am trying to produce is looking like this, with one facet per `var`, the two factor levels as `level1` and `level2` (corresponding to 1 and 2), and the line segment is created from the `level1` value on the left and the `level2` value on the right. Thus the final chart should have five line segments, with slopes that reflect the gains in the `gain` column.

[image]

I am trying this:

```
ggplot(gains.df, aes(level1,level2)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~var)
```

Which unfortunately produces this, and gives the odd values on the horizontal axis too.

[image]

I feel like I am missing something very straightforward and seeking some advice. Here is the data. Thank you.

```
gains.df <- structure(list(var = structure(1:5, .Label = c("x1", "x2", "x3", 
"x4", "x5"), class = "factor"), level1 = c(12.4422350148863, 
16.2432212378588, 16.5408518645381, 16.0000771728686, 15.6246308859921
), level2 = c(16.155087746947, 12.3541015239745, 12.0564708972952, 
12.5972455889646, 12.9726918758412), gain = c(-3.71285273206076, 
3.88911971388437, 4.48438096724297, 3.40283158390399, 2.65193901015094
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two terms of `ggplot(aes()` refer to the x and y values, respectively, so it helps to reshape your data into longer format before it goes into ggplot. In this case, I've shifted the column names into a new column "level" and the values that were there into a new column "value."

```
library(tidyverse)
gains.df %>%
  select(-gain) %>%
  pivot_longer(-var, "level", "value") %>%
  # tidyr::pivot_longer is new in v1.0.0; older versions of tidyr could use:
  # tidyr::gather(level, value, -var)
  ggplot(aes(level, value, group = var)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~var)
```

[image]

Comment: Note to other readers of this solution: make sure you have the most up to date `tidyr` package that contains `pivot_longer` function